# Jquery not working "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" event use jquery library

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have to implement sign up form using a bootstrap popup. I have used below library for same. I want to use jquery validation but it's also not  working

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

However I get this error:

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: it seems that jquery library not loaded. try to remove https and check like this:-`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
`

Comment: @AlivetoDie. error still same

Comment: You may have called one of this JS more than once. Check your masterpage or Layout and your current page. This can be occure if you call them more than once

Comment: I said one of this may have called twice

Comment: @Rush.2707. Yes. I understand. I d'not have used one of them twice